# How to find EUR/JPY chart for particular date and time

Tags: stocks, foreign-exchange, currency

Is it possible to find exchange rates for particular date and time. For example can I find EUR/JPY chart on 30th Oct 2015 at 20:31?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using [MetaTrader](http://www.metaquotes.net) you can jump directly to a certain date/time by following these steps:

1. Press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> and type `Symbol,Period`. For instance `EURJPY,1`.
2. Press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> and type `YYYY.MM.DD HH:MM`, in your case that would be `2015.10.30 20:31`.

Skip step 1 if you already have the **EUR/JPY** chart open.

Answer (score 0):

[oanda.com](http://www.oanda.com/currency/historical-rates/) stores historical exchange rates, but only to daily accuracy.